# Mirroring sites through cURL

Tags: php, regex, curl

Is it possible to 'mirror' a website using cURL?

So basically I have www.mysite.com and www.stackoverflow.com which is the site I would like to mirror.

When I load `www.mysite.com` I want it to call a cURL function that downloads `www.stackoverflow.com` homepage and display it to the user, but before it does, I need to have some sort of a regex to edit all the links (also css/js links) to something like `www.mysite.com/?page=/questions`

I know that things like the search, and of course the 'ask question' features will not work, but the general browsing of the site should be fine, right?

How would you go about doing something like that?

Thanks,

Comment: It is regarded as bad style to rip off the hard work of other sites. Link to the site instead of creating yet another worthless content scraping site.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, however I don't intend to 'rip off the hard work of other sites' or create 'another worthless content scraping site'.

Comment: If it's for stackoverflow / stackexchange only, you might want to have a look at the official API (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-public-beta-starts/) or one of the already available PHP implementations (http://stackapps.com/questions/319/phpstack-a-php-wrapper-to-the-se-api or http://stackapps.com/questions/826/stack-php-clean-easy-to-use-wrapper-for-php-stack-php-0-3-released).

Comment: This is how "WayBackMachine" works aka "Internet Archive" (I think) also there are perfectly normal reasons to do this--it's your own website, or you have permission, or you want to study offline, or you want to translate the website, you're only limited by your imagination. Unfortunately, protecting all these walled gardens stops a lot of innovation from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache's mod_proxy may help you do what you want: deploy an Apache system with mod_proxy and mod_proxy_html to rewrite links: http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

But please oh please don't make yet another worthless content scraping site -- use this for good, not evil. :)

Comment: Will that allow me to change the data from the original website? or just mirror it?

Comment: mod_proxy_html is quite configurable: http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/config.html I'm sure if you've got a change that can't be easily configured, they'd be willing to talk with you about adding the features you need.

Comment: I second "please oh please don't make yet another worthless content scraping site -- use this for good, not evil."

Answer (score 7):

wget is very nice for this task.

Just run from your command line:

```
wget -mkx -e robots=off http://the-site-you-want-to-mirror.com
```

And it'll download all the pages, images, stylesheets, js files etc to a local directory and rewrite all the links so they work locally.

If it's not your own server, be nice and add `-w 2` to add a 2 second delay between page requests.

Comment: What does `-e robots=off` do?

Comment: "If you know what you are doing and really really wish to turn off the robot exclusion, set the robots variable to ‘off’ in your .wgetrc. You can achieve the same effect from the command line using the -e switch, e.g. ‘wget -e robots=off url...’." from https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Robot-Exclusion.html

Just chuffed to find a @kyle-mathews answer from 2k11 :D

Comment: wget is not curl

Answer (score 1):

well you better do a redirect.

or if you want to have your url shown in the browser use frames...

**UPDATE:**

but if you wan't to change the html load the curl-answer into a `div`. you can parse the answer before. with php i.e. `str_replace("www.stackoverflow.com", "www.mysite.com", $curl_answer);`

Comment: I would like to change some stuff on the page before I display it to users, so I have to use something like cURL that allows me to play around with the data.